# which Kid that has most candies algorithm problem

Tags: javascript, array-algorithms

I am on leetcode working on this problem:

Given an array candies and the integer extraCandies, where candies[i] represents the number of candies that the **ith** kid has.
For each kid check if there is a way to distribute extraCandies among the kids such that he or she can have the greatest number of candies among them. Notice that multiple kids can have the greatest number of candies.

Ex 1:

- Input: candies = [2,3,5,1,3], extraCandies = 3
- Output: [true,true,true,false,true]

Explanation:

- Kid 1 has 2 candies and if he or she receives all extra candies (3) will have 5 candies --- the greatest number of candies among the kids.
- Kid 4 has 1 candy and even if he or she receives all extra candies will only have 4 candies.
- Kid 5 has 3 candies and if he or she receives at least 2 extra candies will have the greatest number of candies among the kids.

I put `console.log('true')` & `console.log('false')` so i can see the true/false print whenever the code is succesfully executing its function. But it just prints `true` one time only.

Here is my code. Please tell me what I have wrong or what I am missing:

```js
const candies = [2, 3, 5, 1, 3]
const extraCandies = 3;

 

var kidsWithCandies = (candies, extraCandies) => {
 
  var max = candies.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.max(a, b);
  });

  var min = candies.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return Math.min(a, b);
  });
  console.log(min)
  console.log(max)

  for (let i = 0; i < candies.length; i++) {
    if (candies[i] === max) {
      return true
    } else if (candies[i] = candies[i] + extraCandies < max) {
      return false
    } else if (candies[i] = candies[i] + extraCandies > max) {
      return true
    } else if (candies[i] === min) {
      //> max
      candies[i] = candies[i] + extraCandies
      if (candies[i] > max) {
        return true
      } else if (candies[i] < max) {
        return false
      }

    }
  };
}
```

Comment: `min` and `max` are local to the `minMax` function, you can't use them in `kidsWithCandies`.

Comment: You need to return them from the function, and assign the result to the variables.

Comment: (candies[i] = candies[i] + extraCandies < max) seems to be not as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These'll pass in JavaScript:

```js
const kidsWithCandies = (candies, extraCandies) => {
    const maxCandies = Math.max(...candies);
    return candies.map(candy => candy + extraCandies >= maxCandies);
};

console.log(kidsWithCandies(candies = [2, 3, 5, 1, 3], extraCandies = 3))
```

```js
const kidsWithCandies = (candies, extraCandies) => {
    let maxCandies = 0;
    const greatest = [];

    for (const candy of candies) {
        (candy > maxCandies) && (maxCandies = candy);
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < candies.length; ++index) {
        greatest.push(candies[index] + extraCandies >= maxCandies);
    }
    return greatest;
};

console.log(kidsWithCandies(candies = [4,2,1,1,2], extraCandies = 1))
```

> Spread syntax (...) allows an iterable such as an array expression or
> string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for
> function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an
> object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more
> key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def kidsWithCandies(self, candies, extraCandies):
        max_candies = max(candies)
        return [candy + extraCandies >= max_candies for candy in candies]
```

#### Java

In Java, we'd use `Arrays.stream`:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final List<Boolean> kidsWithCandies(int[] candies, int extraCandies) {
        int maxCandies = Arrays.stream(candies).max().getAsInt();
        return Arrays.stream(candies).mapToObj(candy -> candy + extraCandies >= maxCandies).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The runtime is an order of N.

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/kids-with-the-greatest-number-of-candies/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.
- [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thanks for answering Emma, I edited the post and removed the function minMax from the main function. I accidentally left it in the code. I thought I had removed it. I dont really understand the spread operator. Could you explain it to me? And how did you get rid of the need for having the if/else statement?